# How To Share On Facebook And Twitter (Social Framework) by taking screenshot?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller

In my app, when the user clicks `shareToFacebook` button, I need my app to take a screenshot from another ViewController which just has got the score, and share it to Facebook. So I wrote the code like this: (It works pretty well), :

```
@IBAction func sharetoFacebook() {
var sharetoFacebook : SLComposeViewController = 
SLComposeViewController(forServiceType:
SLServiceTypeFacebook)
sharetoFacebook.setInitialText("WOW! I scored \(rightCounter) right..! Wanna challenge me?")
shareToFacebook.addImage(UIImage(named: "//What should I put here ?"))
self.presentViewController(sharetoFacebook, animated:
    true, completion: nil)  }
```

Now, my doubt is: in order to take that screenshot from another ViewController which has got the score, what code should I put into this :

```
shareToFacebook.addImage(UIImage(named: "//What should I put here ?"))
```

Btw, thanks in advance! It would be a great help!

Comment: I won't put this as an answer because I'm not at my machine and can't test it, but I think all you want to do is use `imageWithData` instead of the default creator you're invoking. Get the data from the other VC and drop that in here. It's sort of like using a Stream, if you're familiar with them under .Net.

Answer (score 0):

Create an extension for `UIView` and have a snapshot method. This will return `UIImage` for any view including subviews.

```
extension UIView {

    func snapshot() -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)

        drawViewHierarchyInRect(self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)

        let sreenshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return screenshotImage
    }
}
```

If you are placing this method on VC

```
func snapshot() -> UIImage {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)

            drawViewHierarchyInRect(self.view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)

        let sreenshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return screenshotImage
    }
```

Comment: So, where should I put this code into ? Is it the ViewController with the score ?

Comment: if you are putting this in view controller then replace bounds.size to self.view.bounds.size, and replace self.bounds to self.view.bounds

Comment: And, so inside the IBAction I should put `shareToFacebook.addImage(UIImage(named: "\(screenshotImage)"))` ? Will that work ? And, it is like..when the share button is clicked..the facebook post option should come up with the screenshot from the ViewController I mentioned earlier. And that ViewController with the score in it should not be shown at all..!

Comment: no the function I mentioned returns an UIImage so you should do something like shareToFacebook.addImage(scoreVC.snaphot())

Comment: Ah..! So that will work ? Thanks I will try it out..and let you know soon..!

Comment: Btw, @Vig Thanks..Man..! You're a life saver..! :) ThankYou..! I'll work it out and let you know soon..

Comment: I tried it out..! And..Im getting a error saying : `Use of unresolved identifier 'drawViewHierarchyInRect' ` ..! And, when Im calling `shareToFacebook.addImage(scoreVC.snapshot())` Im getting missing argument for parameter #1 call..! Sorry..Im a newbie..!  Please help.!

Comment: How to retrieve `screenshotImage` , beacause that variable `screenshotImage` is in another ViewController right ?